# Why is zinc electrode at a higher potential than copper electrode in a galvanic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

I read somewhere that this happens because of better shielding of outer s electrons due to completely filled d orbitals of zinc, but I didn't understand it.
Since Zn has an electronic configuration of [Ar]4s² 3d¹⁰
And Cu has [Ar] 4s¹ 3d¹⁰
Both are having completely filled d orbitals so both of them should be having equal shielding.

Please explain how the above theory is right and if not right what comes into play?

Comment: For an extremely thorough discussion of the findamentals, see this paper: K. Schmidt-Rohr, "How Batteries Store and Release Energy: Explaining Basic Electrochemistry", J. Chem. Ed., 95 (10) (2018) 1801-1810. The Zn and Cu Daniell cell, which is what you specifically ask about, is addressed in great detail. TL; DR Cohesive energy differences are the major factor in explaining the behavior.

Comment: It is the opposite - zinc is at lower potential than copper. IIRC, standard Redox potentials are -0.76 V for Zn/Zn^2+ and +0.34 V for Cu/Cu^2+.

Comment: It is not only about metals, but also about their ions.

Answer (score 3):

I too have read this about "shielding" in the Libretext article on Standard Electrode Potentials, and thought it dubious.

The Schmidt-Rohr paper seems excellent. According to it, the main factor is that d orbitals in Cu can participate in metallic bonding (via promotion of a d electron to the unfilled s), whereas they can't in Zn as all the subshells are full. This leads to a lower "lattice" or cohesive energy in metallic Zn compared to Cu, which is reflected in properties such as melting point and hardness, as well as in greater tendency for an ion to escape from the metal in an electrochemical reaction.